# Math for high school probability

Tags: probability

" A gun is fired at a target. The probability of hitting the target is $0.9$ for each round. The shots are assumed to be independent. Compute the probability that, in order to hit the target properly:

$a$) It takes more than two shots

$b$) The number of shots required is between four and six (i.e. four and six are included in the set) "

This is the other question which I'm confused.
the prob of success is $0.9$ and the prob of failure is $0.1$
in $a$ part)
for it takes $2$ shots:
$0.1\space \text {x} \space $$0.9=0.09$

and what can i
I do for more than $2$ shots?

and in part $b$)
i think i should calculate for $4$ shots + $5$ shots + $6$ shots
I mean for $4$ shots=
$0.1\space \text {x} \space 0.1\space \text {x} \space0.1\space \text {x} \space0.9$
for $5$ shots=
$0.1\space \text {x} \space0.1\space \text {x} \space0.1\space \text {x} \space0.1\space \text {x} \space0.9$
and for $6$ shots=
$0.1\space \text {x} \space0.1\space \text {x} \space0.1\space \text {x} \space0.1\space \text {x} \space0.1\space \text {x} \space0.9$

As a conclusion of part $b$ I should add three of them?

Comment: You should say "from 4 to 6". The only integer between 4 and 6 is the number 5, in spite of what innumerable innumerate TV news broadcasters say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and what can i I do for more than 2 shots?

Use the converse probability. The probability  it takes more than two shots is ONE MINUS the probability that it takes two or less shots:

$$P(X> 2)=1-P(X\leq 2)=1-P(X=2)-P(X=1)=1-0.1\cdot 0.9-0.9$$

> As a conclusion of part b I should add three of them?

That´s right.

Comment: For the first  Q you can also say that the prob. that the first 2 shots are misses is (0.1)(0.1)=0.01 which is the same as the prob.  that it takes more than to shots to get a hit.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, that's good.